# I scrape with requests, however in certain sites, even if I select or find, an empty value is passed

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

I scrape with requests, but in certain sites, even if I select or find, an empty value is passed.

I am a student studying coding.
I am doing airbnb clone coding, but when I run the code, the find or selected value does not come over.
The weird thing is, I brought it up well until yesterday, but I can't suddenly bring it from today.

**In the code below, the result value of 'print(result)' is <Response [200]>**

**I want the value of "Amazing Private Ocean Apartment B" to appear when I do'print(results)' in the code below. However, the result is [].**

To solve the issue, I put headers and tried selenium, but the result is the same.
I want to solve it. Thanks for reading.

**This is code using 'requests'.**

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36'}

URL_BASE = "https://www.airbnb.co.kr/rooms/7310880?adults=1&location=%EA%B4%8C&check_in=2020-09-09&check_out=2020-09-12&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=bb31f4a7-3e38-47f6-8dd7-2d55e6de5bf9"

result = requests.get(URL_BASE, headers = headers)
#time.sleep(3)                                          #When this code is present, both get an error
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.select('._14i3z6h')                      #('._e296pg > ._mbmcsn > ._14i3z6h') I've tried this too
print(results)
```

**PS.Other sites work well for scraping the desired part.**